# Filemaker 11 Certification

Tags: filemaker

I want to take the [Filemaker Certified Developer](http://www.filemaker.com/support/training/certification/) course. What reading material, or web-tutorials, would you suggest to prepare for the course?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would highly suggest that you go thru the FileMaker Training Series (FTS) http://www.filemaker.com/support/training/fts.html in order to study for the exam. [FileMaker Pro 11: The Missing Manual](http://www.google.com/products/catalog?tbm=shop&cid=3286331266214724374) is also a good resource.

Good luck, I know very seasoned developers who have not passed the exam.